# How to make calculations across two different lists of dataframes?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply, calculation

I have two lists of data frames, such that data is a list of 47 data frames, where each data frame has columns [coords, x, y, liklihood, x.1, x.2, liklihood.1, etc.] and dataA is a list of 47 data frames each of the same length as those in data, but with fewer columns [coords, x, y] that represent different coordinates.

I want to create a third list, or add a column to each data frame in one of the lists, that will contain the distance calculation from pointDistance(p1, p2) where p1 is the x and y columns of each data frame in list data, and p2 is the x and y columns of each data frame in list dataA.

I am trying to keep the dataframes in lists rather than having 47*2 individual data frames in my global environment.

Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
coords <- rnorm(10)
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
liklihood <- rnorm(10)
x.1 <- rnorm(10)
y.1 <- rnorm(10)

day1 <-  data.frame(coords,x,y,liklihood,x.1,y.1)

coords <- rnorm(10)
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
liklihood <- rnorm(10)
x.1 <- rnorm(10)
y.1 <- rnorm(10)

day2 <-  data.frame(coords,x,y,liklihood,x.1,y.1)

data <- list(day1,day2)

coords <- rnorm(10)
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
liklihood <- rnorm(10)

day1 <-  data.frame(coords,x,y,liklihood)

coords <- rnorm(10)
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
liklihood <- rnorm(10)


day2 <-  data.frame(coords,x,y,liklihood)

dataA <- list(day1,day2)
```

Comment: Could you add a [minimale reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)? The MRE will make it easier for others to find and test a answer to your question. That way you can help others to help you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your distance calculation function?

Comment: I can't figure out how to make calculations across the lists to even really try anything... I am using the pointDistance function: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.0-12/topics/pointDistance

Comment: You could use loops for that. For each entry in data you calculate the distance to each entry ind dataA. Loops within loops ;) If you are not sure how to do that I highly suggest checking some of the many R tutorials.

Comment: Maybe I misread your question and you want something else.. I'm not sure I understand what you meant with: *pointDistance(p1, p2) where p1 is the x and y columns of* **each** *data frame in list data, and p2 is the x and y columns of **each** data frame in list dataA.*

Comment: You got an answer from Allan Cameron. If this answered your question you  should accept it (by clicking on the check mark) and could consider up-voting it. If it did not answer your question I'd suggest updating the question and clarifying  what it is you want and add an example how the result should look like. That way you can help others to help you ;)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mapply` in base R to do this.

First, write a function that would return a single correct data frame if it was given a pair of data frames from your two lists, like `data[[1]]` and `dataA[[1]]`

```r
library(raster)

append_distances <- function(df1, df2)
{
  df1$distance <- pointDistance(cbind(df1$x, df1$y), cbind(df2$x, df2$y), lonlat = FALSE)
  return(df1)
}
```

Now we just pass this function and your two lists to `mapply`:

```
data <-  mapply(append_distances, data, dataA, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

and now each data frame in`data` has a distance column added:

```r
data
#> [[1]]
#>        coords          x           y  liklihood         x.1        y.1  distance
#> 1   0.4761741  0.7913819  0.11597299 -0.6159504 -0.17626836 -0.8649915 2.1378779
#> 2   0.2608518  0.4389639 -1.44510285 -0.5452702 -2.31927588 -0.5114613 3.0321765
#> 3   2.1098629  0.3457442  1.59630572 -0.3205454  0.25760236  1.6791924 0.4150714
#> 4   0.5937334 -0.2043505  0.23667944 -0.2480409 -0.52856599 -0.4263619 1.6662791
#> 5   0.2819461 -1.9768319  0.68344331 -0.4975349 -0.08315893  0.9271072 2.3841079
#> 6   0.5779044 -0.5706433  0.89377684 -1.0084165 -0.83697268  0.9928353 0.6818632
#> 7   0.1410554 -0.6133513  0.25957971 -0.1781339 -0.77489990 -0.7191718 0.8303696
#> 8  -1.1769578  0.9203776 -0.06258728 -0.8991639 -0.38907408 -0.8388408 0.5028145
#> 9  -0.1388739 -0.8279408  1.15568431 -0.3312423  1.17269754 -1.4530041 1.6042288
#> 10 -0.3755364  0.6285803  0.52453490  0.7323463 -0.49051839 -0.1949171 0.6205714
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>        coords           x          y  liklihood        x.1          y.1  distance
#> 1   2.2158425  0.16430566 -0.5721804 -0.7523029  0.2866881 -2.027529031 0.4418775
#> 2   1.5753250 -0.67190607 -0.1140359 -0.3125333 -0.5361148  0.153228235 1.7182954
#> 3   0.8558108  1.19404509 -1.5834463  0.3858246  0.4475970  0.460910344 1.6229581
#> 4   0.8027824  0.76579023 -0.5938679  0.5592208  0.5883806  0.231569460 3.3608275
#> 5  -1.1487244  0.01013471  0.6855049  0.7148735 -2.2822053  1.918921619 2.3790501
#> 6   0.1014336  0.73941541 -0.4487482  0.1758588  0.8579709  0.029777437 1.8923570
#> 7  -0.8238857  0.67911991 -0.9140873 -0.6887611 -1.0709704 -0.009789701 1.4694983
#> 8  -0.1553338  0.78560221 -0.8218460 -0.5537232  0.7295692  0.744225760 2.4279377
#> 9  -0.6297834  0.09747354  0.2048211 -1.0849396 -0.2201589  0.173386536 0.8638957
#> 10 -0.4616377 -0.51116686  0.3204535 -0.5285903  1.0053890 -0.534173400 1.0715881
```